# How to update a column using mapping table's columns which doesn't have a unique key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables, `master` and `mapping`. I need to update a column in `Master` table called `lane` based on mapping table's column `lane`. However, in the `mapping` table, I don't have a unique key, so I need to use a combination of 4 columns to match with the 4 columns of the `master` table. Now the problem is in my mapping table I don't have all the values filled in 3 of the columns, it has many `NULL` values.

Master table looks like this:

[image: Master Table]

Mapping table looks like this:

[image: Mapping Table]

I tried with DECODE function in MERGE statement but it's not working.

```
MERGE INTO MASTER_DATA MA
   USING(SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D, LANE
   FROM MAPPING) MAP
   ON (DECODE(MAP.A, MA.A, 1, 0) = 1
   AND DECODE(MAP.B, MA.B, 1, NULL, 1, 0) = 1
   AND DECODE(MAP.C, MA.C, 1, NULL, 1, 0) = 1
   AND DECODE(MAP.D, MA.D, 1, NULL, 1, 0) = 1
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET LCA.LANE = MAP.LANE;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_data (
    a    VARCHAR2(10),
    b    VARCHAR2(5),
    c    VARCHAR2(5),
    d    VARCHAR2(5),
    lane VARCHAR2(5)
);

CREATE TABLE mapping (
    a    VARCHAR2(10),
    b    VARCHAR2(5),
    c    VARCHAR2(5),
    d    VARCHAR2(5),
    lane VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT ALL
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'Arya',   NULL,  NULL,    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'Rajput', NULL,  'Kumar', NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     'Raj', NULL,    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'Arya',   NULL,  Kumar,    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Rina', 'Arora', NULL,  NULL, NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Rina', NULL,     'Bisht', NULL,    NULL)
 INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Rina', Gua,     NULL, 'Ahuja',    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', 'AA',   'BB',  'CC',    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', 'BB', 'CC',  NULL, NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', NULL,     NULL, 'EY',    NULL)
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'Arya',   NULL,  NULL,    'BR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     NULL,  NULL,    'CR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     NULL,  'Kumar', 'MR')
 INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Rina', NULL,   NULL,  NULL,    'NR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Rina', NULL,     NULL,  'Ahuja',    'LR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', 'AA',     NULL,  NULL, 'GX') INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', 'BB',   NULL,  NULL,    'KX')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('NOX', NULL,     NULL,  NULL,    'EX')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

I am expecting, this should update the Lane based on maximum matching columns, like the least matches it finds in among the 2 tables and ignore NULL. My result should look like this:
[image: Output]

Comment: Please do not post images of data. [Edit] your question and include the sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that we can copy-paste and execute and the expected output as a table containing text formatted using markdown.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include an English (not code) description of the logic that you want to implement. Why does the `CR` row of the mapping table map to the `Raj` row of the master table? Why does it not map to one of the other rows?

Comment: Because, I don't have a value 'raj' in C column in the mapping table, so I want this to be updated with the least matching columns, which is column A in this case. So based on matching column A, it's updated to CR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nvl` while joining, to handle the nulls

```
merge into master mr
using mapping mp
on (
nvl(mr.a, 0) = nvl(mp.a, 0)
and nvl(mr.b, 0) = nvl(mp.b, 0)
and nvl(mr.c, 0) = nvl(mp.c, 0)
and nvl(mr.d, 0) = nvl(mp.d, 0)
)
when matched then
update
set 
mr.lane = mp.lane;
```

Comment: You have a typo `mvl` instead of `nvl` and this only updates a single row. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8n9EgbY)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but it's not updating the 2nd row of the main table.

Comment: It does not update, because not all the columns are matching with both the tables

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is to match even at least a single column is matching then also it should update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prioritise the rows based on the matches and assign the lane according to the best matches. You can do that by joining all main table rows to corresponding mapping table rows and assigning each column a numeric value depending on whether it matches or not and then ranking the matches across both main and mapping table rows and finding the best matches.

This works for your sample data, you will need to test it on larger samples of data to see if it meets your requirements for that data as well:

```sql
MERGE INTO main_data m
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT m.ROWID AS rid,
           p.LANE,
           RANK() OVER (
             PARTITION BY m.ROWID
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.b = p.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    + CASE WHEN m.c = p.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    + CASE WHEN m.d = p.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC NULLS LAST
           ) AS main_rank,
           RANK() OVER (
             PARTITION BY p.ROWID
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.b = p.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    + CASE WHEN m.c = p.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    + CASE WHEN m.d = p.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC NULLS LAST
           ) AS map_rank
    FROM   main_data m
           INNER JOIN mapping p
           ON (m.a = p.a
              AND (m.b = p.b OR m.b IS NULL OR p.b IS NULL)
              AND (m.c = p.c OR m.c IS NULL OR p.c IS NULL)
              AND (m.d = p.d OR m.d IS NULL OR p.d IS NULL))
  )
  WHERE  main_rank = 1 AND map_rank = 1
) p
ON (m.ROWID = p.RID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET lane = p.lane;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_data (
  a VARCHAR2(8),
  b VARCHAR2(8),
  c VARCHAR2(8),
  d VARCHAR2(8),
  lane VARCHAR2(2)
);

CREATE TABLE mapping (
  a VARCHAR2(8),
  b VARCHAR2(8),
  c VARCHAR2(8),
  d VARCHAR2(8),
  lane VARCHAR2(2)
);

INSERT ALL
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'arya',   NULL,  NULL,    NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'rajput', NULL,  'kumar', NULL)
  INTO main_data (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     'raj', NULL,    NULL)
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', 'arya',   NULL,  NULL,    'BR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     NULL,  NULL,    'CR')
  INTO mapping (a, b, c, d, lane) VALUES ('Sona', NULL,     NULL,  'kumar', 'MR')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

| A | B | C | D | LANE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sona | arya | *null* | *null* | BR |
| Sona | rajput | *null* | kumar | MR |
| Sona | *null* | raj | *null* | CR |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4anjYdTQ)

#### Update

For your expanded sample data, you can use try finding the best single match for each row:

```sql
MERGE INTO main_data m
USING (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT mp.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY mp.rid
             ORDER BY main_rank + map_rank
           ) AS rn
    FROM   (
      SELECT m.ROWID AS rid,
             p.lane,
             RANK() OVER (
               PARTITION BY m.ROWID
               ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.b = p.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                      + CASE WHEN m.c = p.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                      + CASE WHEN m.d = p.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC NULLS LAST
             ) AS main_rank,
             RANK() OVER (
               PARTITION BY p.ROWID
               ORDER BY CASE WHEN m.b = p.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                      + CASE WHEN m.c = p.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                      + CASE WHEN m.d = p.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC NULLS LAST
             ) AS map_rank
      FROM   main_data m
             INNER JOIN mapping p
             ON (m.a = p.a
                AND (m.b = p.b OR m.b IS NULL OR p.b IS NULL)
                AND (m.c = p.c OR m.c IS NULL OR p.c IS NULL)
                AND (m.d = p.d OR m.d IS NULL OR p.d IS NULL))
    ) mp
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
) p
ON (m.ROWID = p.RID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET lane = p.lane;
```

Which, after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| A | B | C | D | LANE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sona | Arya | *null* | *null* | BR |
| Sona | Rajput | *null* | Kumar | MR |
| Sona | *null* | Raj | *null* | CR |
| Sona | Arya | *null* | Kumar | MR |
| Rina | Arora | *null* | *null* | NR |
| Rina | *null* | Bisht | *null* | NR |
| Rina | Gua | *null* | Ahuja | LR |
| NOX | AA | BB | CC | GX |
| NOX | BB | CC | *null* | KX |
| NOX | *null* | *null* | EY | EX |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xFgShyuS)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I tried this on my data, I only got 900 rows updated however I have data approx. 30 lakhs.

Comment: @SonaliArya We cannot test data we cannot see. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77946843/edit) your question and include a more complete set of sample data (as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements we can copy-paste and **NOT** as images) and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: I have added more examples in it, hope it helps.

Comment: @SonaliArya Updated - it doesn't quite match your sample data but it does appear to match your requirements as some of the rows can have multiple matches (more than you marked in your expected output).

Comment: I tried the updated code, somehow it is giving error 
ORA-00904: "M"."ROWID": invalid identifier

Comment: @SonaliArya [`ROWID` is a pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROWID-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-F6E0FBD2-983C-495D-9856-5E113A17FAF1) that acts like a direct pointer to the table's row; if your data is stored in a table then it should have that pseudo-column (and I'm confused why you don't as all tables have it). I'm not sure how you would correlate between the sub-query generating the `LANE` values and the main table if you don't have a unique way of identifying rows.